# How to match a regex pattern with negative lookbehind on JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex, negative-lookbehind

I need help with a JavaScript regular Expressions trouble. In words, I have the new regex to match non escaped dollars:

```
private readonly boundary: RegExp =  /(?<!\\)\$/;
```

But the problem is that it's a Negative LookBehind technique, which is only implemented in newest JavaScript processors (only latest version of Chrome implements it). This regex it's part of a more complex regex, so I need to solve it with the regex definition. So I need to write that expression using standard techniques. Does someone help me?

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/wrvyvQ/2/) I've created a template to work on the problem.